# Разобрать XML в PHP с помощью SimpleXML

Tags: php, массивы, simplexml

Сторонний API по моему запросу выдает мне вот такой массив:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [count] => 1 ) [order] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [orderno] => 1111111 [awb] => 1111111 [orderno2] => 1 [ordercode] => 4796 [givencode] => ) [barcode] => 1111111 [sender] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [company] => ЧЛ НАЛИЧНЫМИ [person] => - [town] => Алматы город [address] => - [phone] => - [contacts] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ) [date] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [time_min] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [time_max] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [receiver] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [company] => hhhh [person] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [phone] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [contacts] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ) [inn] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [zipcode] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [town] => Алматы город [address] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [date] => 2022-06-14 [time_min] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [time_max] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [coords] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [lat] => [lon] => ) ) [deliveryPIN] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [pickup] => NO [return] => NO [weight] => 5 [return_weight] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [quantity] => 1 [paytype] => CASH [print_check] => NO [service] => 1 [return_service] => 1 [type] => 1 [return_type] => 1 [waittime] => 0 [price] => 2500.00 [inshprice] => 2500.00 [enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [instruction] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [basestatus] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [code] => 0 ) ) [currcoords] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [lat] => [lon] => [accuracy] => [RequestDateTime] => ) ) [courier] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [code] => 1 [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [phone] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [deliveryprice] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [total] => 2800.00 [delivery] => 2800.00 [return] => 0.00 ) ) [receiverpays] => NO [acceptpartially] => YES [status] => NEW [statushistory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [customstatecode] => 1 [clientstatecode] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [department] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [return_message] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [deliveredto] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [delivereddate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [deliveredtime] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [outstrbarcode] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [partner] => Офис в Алматы [arrival] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [costcode] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [receipt] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [items] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ) [packages] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ) ) )
```

Я, к сожалению, понятия не имею, как разделить его построчно, для удобочитаемости. Но суть в следующем. Мне нужно вытащить оттуда элемент `price => 2500.00`. Делаю так:

```
foreach($myarr->order as $arr){
   echo $arr['price'];
}
```

Но не получается. Что я делаю не так, подскажите пожалуйста новичку? Спасибо!

Comment: где в приведённом коде работа с simplexml?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский $output = curl_exec($ch);
$myarr = new SimpleXMLElement($output);

Comment: Приведите в вопросе сам xml

Comment: @splash58 я немного не понимаю, как это сделать. По curl запросу мне сторонний API отдаёт то, что я привёл в вопросе (с помощью print_r($myarr)). Я не программист, но учусь. Как я понял из того, что успел нагуглить, такой массив разбирается в цикле таким образом, как я привёл в вопросе. Но он не разбирается)

Comment: `$output = curl_exec($ch); echo $output;` - это просто текст